# UILabel in a NSMutableArray unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsmutablearray, uilabel

In my app, I have created a 'NSMutalbeArray', in which I add some 'UILabel'.

I correctly initialize my array :

```
_pickerMonthLabel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I correctly add UILabels in my array, but when I want to make some changes to a label, the behavior is strange. For example, I want to change the text color of a label in my array. I do :

```
[(UILabel *)[_pickerMonthLabel objectAtIndex:i] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

This doesn't look like to work because my app crashes :

```
-[__NSCFConstantString setTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e8d4
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString setTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e8d4'
```

But i have no warning when I wrote this line. When  I write another kind of line :

```
(UILabel *)[_pickerMonthLabel objectAtIndex:i].textcolor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It gives me an error :

```
Property 'textcolor' not found on object of type 'id'
```

I don't understand the difference between these two lines, and how to fix my problem...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The error indicates that your array contains `NSString` objects, not `UILabel` objects. Are you sure you adding the label to the array and not the label's text?

Comment: Thank you Maddy for your answer. At the starting point, I add NSString, but I replace all of them by UILabels, this is really strange. I used "insert object at index" to replace nsstring by my labels

Comment: The error indicates that you did not replace all of the strings with labels.

Comment: You have the solution, all the nsstring doesn't look to be replaced... Really strange

Comment: You're trying to do setTextColor on an NSString.  Figure out why you have an NSString instead of a UILabel -- it's a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: If you're using an insert method then you aren't replacing...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more of a remark, but you could try to use the respondsToSelector: message to check if the instance can handle the message you are trying to send. (This will make sure you don't get an exception) In your case this would be:

```
if ([[_pickerMonthLabel objectAtIndex:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(setTextColor:)]){
    [(UILabel *)[_pickerMonthLabel objectAtIndex:i] setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
// add this to see what your class is
//else{
//   NSLog(@"The class is: %@", [[_pickerMonthLabel objectAtIndex:i] class]);
//}
```

Hope it helps your debugging.